# How to send response code from python using cgi package

Tags: python, html, apache, http, cgi

I am writing a script in python using cgi package. I need to send response of either **HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n**    or    **HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n**    based on some checks in my code. If I print one of the above line as the first line of my response my apache server logs an error and returns     **500 Internal server error**    The relevant part of the error message logged in this case is     **malformed header from script 'helo.py': Bad header: HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n**         Can anyone guide me what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you print only these lines? According to the [CGI spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-4.1.3), you must define `Content-Type`.

```
print "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
```

If you want to emit status, please use [`Status`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-6.3.3) header instead (this is CGI, not HTTP header).

So

```
print "Status: 404 Not Found\r\n"
print "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
```

This will do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answer of Sergey I would like to add that for Python 3 you just need the following:

```
print("Status: 404 Not Found")
print("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8\n")
```

Minimal example to show that the above method works

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print("Status: 404 Not Found")
print("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8\n")
print("Hello")
```

[image]

Comment: I use this code above but I always get 200 as Status. Do I need to enable or import something else to make this work? Because my code works if everything goes well, in other words if I always can return a 200 status and some json.dump, my code works